# Scala Map deserialization boxing issue

Tags: java, scala, jackson, deserialization, boxing

I am using jackson for serialization/deserialization.

I have a map: `probs: Map[Int,Double]`

```
[info] 2015-11-11 20:07:13,402$ - Probs: Map(0 -> 0.21180156893441554, 5 -> 0.052510669743843774, 10 -> 0.007307531895689445, 15 -> 5.520217135110417E-4)
[info] 2015-11-11 20:07:13,402$ - Prob keys: Set(0, 5, 10, 15)
[info] java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
[info]  at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(BoxesRunTime.java:106)
```

The deserialized `probs` map (as shown above in the console logs above) is supposed to be of type `Map[Int,Double]`. I get the above error when I try to run: `assert(probs.keys.forall(probs.contains))`

There is some weird boxing thing happening but I can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Where's this data coming from and how exactly are you deserializing it? As currently written, the question doesn't really give us anything to go on.

Comment: My bad. The data is being serialized using the same jackson serializer on the same object. The point is that jackson doesn't throw out any error while deserializing this Map[Int, Double] object.

Comment: How would I reproduce this problem on my own machine?